# Passing a variable to function in Document.write

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I have the following code:

```
var len;
var i;
var str;
len=@model.getProduct_to_displaySize();
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
document.write("<center>"+
     "<a href=\"JavaScript:Platform.Product.openQuickView(@model.getProductID(i))\">"+
"<img src=\"@model.getProductImgURL(i)\">"+
"</a>"+
"</center><br><br>");
}
```

I'm trying to pass the argument i (from the for loop), into a function inside the loop, however I'm getting the following error:

not found: value i

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the `i` into the string:

```
document.write("<center>"+
     "<a href=\"JavaScript:Platform.Product.openQuickView(@model.getProductID("+i+"))\">"+
"<img src=\"@model.getProductImgURL("+i+")\">"+
"</a>"+
"</center><br><br>");
```

Comment: I tried it, it doesn't work.
I get this error:

type mismatch; found : String("+i+") required: Int

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is wrong, but the idea is right. Better yet try it this way.
using a string literal. wrap the i like this --> ${i}

for example: `<center> <img src="${i.url}"> </center>`

using string literal quotes allows you to interpolate values wrapped with dollar sign and braces instead of plus signs all over the place.